# How to solve a memory leak with parent/child self-referencing dependencies in Doctrine Collections

Tags: php, symfony, memory, memory-leaks, doctrine-orm

I'm facing a very subtle memory leak in my entity.

I'm running a PHP daemon and once a collection is loaded, the entities in it are never released from the memory. So I have a small but constant increment in memory consumption that leads to a memory leak. And I don't know how to solve it :)

**The details**

The entity we are speaking of is this (relevant properties and methods only. Complete code [here](https://github.com/Aerendir/bundle-commands-queues/blob/memory-leak/Entity/Job.php)):

```
/**
 * Basic properties and methods o a Job.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SerendipityHQ\Bundle\CommandsQueuesBundle\Repository\JobRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="queues_scheduled_jobs")
 */
class Job
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="SerendipityHQ\Bundle\CommandsQueuesBundle\Entity\Job", inversedBy="parentDependencies", cascade={"detach", "refresh"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="queues_jobs_dependencies",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_job", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="child_job", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *     )
     */
    private $childDependencies;

    /**
     * @var Collection|ArrayCollection|PersistentCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="SerendipityHQ\Bundle\CommandsQueuesBundle\Entity\Job", mappedBy="childDependencies")
     */
    private $parentDependencies;

    ...

    /**
     * @var Job If this Job is a retry of another job, here there is the Job of which this is the retry
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="SerendipityHQ\Bundle\CommandsQueuesBundle\Entity\Job", inversedBy="retriedBy", cascade={"detach", "refresh"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="retry_of", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $retryOf;

    /**
     * @var Job
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="SerendipityHQ\Bundle\CommandsQueuesBundle\Entity\Job", mappedBy="retryOf")
     */
    private $retriedBy;

    /**
     * @var Job If this Job is a retry of another retried job, here there is the first retried Job
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SerendipityHQ\Bundle\CommandsQueuesBundle\Entity\Job", inversedBy="retryingJobs", cascade={"detach", "refresh"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="first_retried_job", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $firstRetriedJob;

    /**
     * @var Collection The Jobs used to retry this one
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SerendipityHQ\Bundle\CommandsQueuesBundle\Entity\Job", mappedBy="firstRetriedJob", cascade={"detach", "refresh"})
     */
    private $retryingJobs;

    /**
     * @param string       $command
     * @param array|string $arguments
     */
    public function __construct(string $command, $arguments = [])
    {
        if (false === is_string($arguments) && false === is_array($arguments)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Second parameter $arguments can be only an array or a string.');
        }

        // If is a String...
        if (is_string($arguments)) {
            // Transform into an array
            $arguments = explode(' ', $arguments);

            // And remove leading and trailing spaces
            $arguments = array_map(function ($value) {
                return trim($value);
            }, $arguments);
        }

        $this->command = $command;
        $this->arguments = $arguments;
        $this->priority = 1;
        $this->queue = 'default';
        $this->status = self::STATUS_NEW;
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
        $this->childDependencies = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->parentDependencies = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->retryStrategy = new NeverRetryStrategy();
        $this->retryingJobs = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @param Job $job
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function addChildDependency(Job $job) : self
    {
        if ($this === $job) {
            throw new \LogicException(
                'You cannot add as dependency the object itself.'
                .' Check your addParentDependency() and addChildDependency() method.'
            );
        }

        if ($this->parentDependencies->contains($job)) {
            throw new \LogicException(
                'You cannot add a child dependecy that is already a parent dependency.'
                .' This will create an unresolvable circular reference.'
            );
        }

        if (false === $this->childDependencies->contains($job)) {
            //\Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper::dump('[Job::addChildDep] ('.$this->getId().') before adding to childs: ' . round(memory_get_usage(true) / 1000000, 2));
            $this->childDependencies->add($job);
            //\Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper::dump('[Job::addChildDep] ('.$job->getId().')before adding parent to given Job: ' . round(memory_get_usage(true) / 1000000, 2));
            $job->addParentDependency($this);
        }

        //\Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper::dump('[Job::addChildDep] after adding: ' . round(memory_get_usage(true) / 1000000, 2));

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Job $job
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function addParentDependency(Job $job) : self
    {
        if ($this === $job) {
            throw new \LogicException(
                'You cannot add as dependency the object itself.'
                .' Check your addParentDependency() and addChildDependency() method.'
            );
        }

        // This Job is already started...
        if (self::STATUS_PENDING === $this->getStatus() || self::STATUS_RUNNING === $this->getStatus()) {
            throw new \LogicException(
                sprintf(
                    'The Job %s has already started. You cannot add a parent dependency.',
                    $this->getId()
                )
            );
        }

        //\Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper::dump('[Job::addParentDep] ('.$this->getId().') before checking childs: ' . round(memory_get_usage(true) / 1000000, 2));
        if (true === $this->childDependencies->contains($job)) {
            throw new \LogicException(
                'You cannot add a parent dependecy that is already a child dependency.'
                .' This will create an unresolvable circular reference.'
            );
        }

        if (false === $this->parentDependencies->contains($job)) {
            //\Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper::dump('[Job::addParentDep] ('.$this->getId().') before adding to parents: ' . round(memory_get_usage(true) / 1000000, 2));
            $this->parentDependencies->add($job);
            //\Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper::dump('[Job::addParentDep] ('.$job->getId().')before adding child to given Job: ' . round(memory_get_usage(true) / 1000000, 2));
            $job->addChildDependency($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

In the `addChilDependency()` and in the `addParentDependency()` methods there are the dumps of the current memory usage. Those are some results:

```
"[Job::addChildDep] () before adding to childs: 23.07"
"[Job::addChildDep] (61)before adding parent to given Job: 23.07"
"[Job::addParentDep] (61) before checking childs: 23.07"
"[Job::addParentDep] (61) before adding to parents: 25.17"
"[Job::addParentDep] ()before adding child to given Job: 25.17"
"[Job::addChildDep] after adding: 25.17"
...
"[Job::addChildDep] () before adding to childs: 25.17"
"[Job::addChildDep] (52)before adding parent to given Job: 25.17"
"[Job::addParentDep] (52) before checking childs: 25.17"
"[Job::addParentDep] (52) before adding to parents: 27.26"
"[Job::addParentDep] ()before adding child to given Job: 27.26"
"[Job::addChildDep] after adding: 27.26"
...
"[Job::addChildDep] () before adding to childs: 27.26"
"[Job::addChildDep] (98)before adding parent to given Job: 27.26"
"[Job::addParentDep] (98) before checking childs: 27.26"
"[Job::addParentDep] (98) before adding to parents: 27.26"
"[Job::addParentDep] ()before adding child to given Job: 27.26"
"[Job::addChildDep] after adding: 27.26"
...
"[Job::addChildDep] () before adding to childs: 27.26"
"[Job::addChildDep] (54)before adding parent to given Job: 27.26"
"[Job::addParentDep] (54) before checking childs: 27.26"
"[Job::addParentDep] (54) before adding to parents: 29.36"
"[Job::addParentDep] ()before adding child to given Job: 29.36"
"[Job::addChildDep] after adding: 29.36"
```

As you can see there is an increment in memory consumption in the `addParentDependency()` method when I use [`$this->childDependencies->contains()`](https://github.com/Aerendir/bundle-commands-queues/blob/memory-leak/Entity/Job.php#L341).

**Now, the problem is not the increment in memory consumption, but, instead, the fact that I cannot free it.**

In fact, I use `EntityManager::detach()` ([here](https://github.com/Aerendir/bundle-commands-queues/blob/memory-leak/Repository/JobRepository.php#L65), [here](https://github.com/Aerendir/bundle-commands-queues/blob/memory-leak/Service/QueuesDaemon.php#L446), [here](https://github.com/Aerendir/bundle-commands-queues/blob/memory-leak/Util/JobsMarker.php#L271) and [here](https://github.com/Aerendir/bundle-commands-queues/blob/memory-leak/Util/JobsMarker.php#L147)) and also [`EntityManager::clear()`](https://github.com/Aerendir/bundle-commands-queues/blob/memory-leak/Service/QueuesDaemon.php#L488) (and then [`gc_collect_cycles()`](https://github.com/Aerendir/bundle-commands-queues/blob/memory-leak/Service/QueuesDaemon.php#L490) - enabled with [`gc_enable()`](https://github.com/Aerendir/bundle-commands-queues/blob/memory-leak/Service/QueuesDaemon.php#L127)).

I'm expecting that the memory goes up and down during the Daemon running, but this isn't true as the memory goes up and never goes down.

I've also taken [other measures](https://github.com/Aerendir/bundle-commands-queues/blob/memory-leak/Service/QueuesDaemon.php#L90) to maintain the memory consumption low, as using `EntityManager->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null)` and `EntityManager->getConfiguration()->setSecondLevelCacheEnabled(false)`. More I've set `cascade="detach", "refresh"` to detach also child dependencies but this seems not working.

So the memory increment is caused by the loading of the `Collection` of child dependencies.

I think I'm facing some problems related to [circular references](https://derickrethans.nl/circular-references.html) but I really don't know how to solve them.

Have you any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried calling unset() on your "no more used" variables? until you don't destroy them garbage collector will consider everything as used variables, another approach is to reduce your code in some smaller functions and start profiling the memory usage

Comment: Unset() should be not required as the variables are destroyed when the method ends being executed. I'm ever more convinced the problem is a circular reference between objects that cause them being "orphan" and so not collectibles by the garbage collector... I'll do some more tests to demonstrate this thesis and try to find a solution.